# Import matplotlib.pyplot as plt - gives error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'

Tags: python

When I use a Python shell this works fine, but when I use a Python file and run the file, I get an error on Line:

> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

The error is:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot', 'matplotlib' is not a package

I installed matplotlib using pip.  I tried three shells and it works.  I tried two environments (Wing and Idle) an it fails.  Is there some Python environment variable that is not set correctly?  What is wrong and how can this be fixed?

Comment: wing and idle are using a different installation of python than your shell

Comment: Please look at using virtual environments. You can check to see if 'matplotlib' is installed by doing 'pip freeze'. Pip installs in a shell are not global but only exist for that session.

Comment: Wing and idle are using Python 3.6.6.  I am using shells from Wing, Idle, and the system command prompt.  Pip freeze shows matplotlib.  Matplotlib appears in site-packages along with pyplot.  I suppose that I could try virtual environments.

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing the name of my test file from matplotlib.py to matplotlibtest.py.  Thanks for your comments.